# How to install play2War plugin (Play Framework 2.1.1.)

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I'd be very grateful if someone could provide me the basic steps to install the Play2War [Plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin). Like where to put the plugin files?, and which files?

I'm pretty new with Play Framework (Java, I'm not a Scala developer, ...yet), just created my first application, and want to deploy it on my server, with is a CentOS with Tomcat/ Glassfish installed, but unfortunately I found out that the 2.x version didn't have the built in **war command** anymore. I scoured the documentation and found the links [Configuration](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Configuration), [Usage](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Usage) and [Deployment](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Deployment), but what I want to know are the steps until get there.

I started looking for **[sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/index.html)** building tool ('cause Play2War [Plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin) uses it), until I realize that **Play Framework 2.1.1.** already have it installed (at least that is what I believe. See: *PLAY_HOME/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar* and *PLAY_HOME/framework/build*). Am I correct?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you have a working play application, you are already using SBT tools to build.  Yes, SBT comes with play.
- The play2war plugin tutorial provides a step-by-step instruction.  Simply follow the tutorial, you should be fine.
- To answer your question, where to put the plugin file?
  As the tutorial suggests, you need to modify files like `APP_HOME/project/plugins.sbt`, `APP_HOME/project/Build.scala`.  You should already have these files, you simply need to add those lines to these existing files.

If you have a specific problem, please provide the error message.

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded the .zip file, which contains the following directories: ext-runtimes/, project-code/, and 2 samples directories (one at singular). Which one should I include to my project? And under which project directory?

Comment: You should not download anything. What you need to do is follow the tutorial, and add this line `addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.0")`, and sbt will pull the artifact from Maven repository.

Comment: Thanks again, 2 firsts steps done, stuck on the 3rd: what is the *project configuration* mentioned at **Add all Play2war settings in your project configuration** [link](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Configuration#add-all-play2war-settings-in-your-project-configuration), not the application.conf, right? I've searched all files in project and didn't found not a word like those.

Answer (score 4):

As Play 2.1.1 already has SBT its as simple as doing the following:

Within plugins.sbt add:

> addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.0")

Then within the Build.scala file add:

```
import com.github.play2war.plugin._
```

...

> val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
>
> ```
> .settings(Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings: _*)
> .settings(Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "X.X")
> ```

The X.X needs to be changed to the required Java Servlet version (usually 3.0 or 2.5 depending on your container)